# How do I draw a straight line 'curve'

Tags: modeling

All I want to do is draw a straight line. "Add curve" and it's.. well, curved. It was so straightforward to model with Amapi without opening 100 drop down boxes. Blender by comparison is really unintuitive. The help just says you can do this or that but not *how*. Any advice?

Edit: Thanks, it's okay now - I had to set the Spine Type to Poly.

Comment: You can select all and V > Vector and you'll have a straight line

Comment: Thank you. I found I had to set the spline type to Poly.

Comment: Or instead of adding a _Bézier_ curve to the scene, you could add a _Path_.

Comment: Easiest way for a straight Bezier curve (for me) is: _Add Bezier Curve > Enter Edit Mode, Press V,V then V,L_ (makes a straight vector curve, then changes handles back to "align").

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the options raised in the commentary to your question,  the shipped add-on 'Add Curve: Extra Objects' makes line available, directly:

[image]